# An Unexpected Circle...

Tags: trigonometry, circles, transformation

I played around with

$$z=\frac{-1+e^{it}}{\phantom{-}2+e^{it}}$$

and found that, when I  draw the real against the imaginary of $z$, it pretty much looks like a circle.

[image]

But neither [${\frak{R}} z $](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real((-1%2B1*exp(-i*pi*t))%2F(2%2B1*exp(-i*pi*t)))), nor ${\frak I} z$ look like $\cos $ or $\sin$. Is it due to a kind of transformed argument of $\cos $ and $\sin$? Something like $\cos(f(t))$?

Comment: Baggins! We hates it forever!

Comment: *My precious,* @Will "Gollum" Jagy. Thanks for the pun...

Comment: I see. They subtitled the movie An Unexpected Journey, i thought you meant that in the first place. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903624/

Comment: Why do you want the old title? I think the suggested one is more descriptive.

Comment: @Ooker a matter of taste and style about my own stuff...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d$ be complex numbers and suppose <s>c,d are not both 0 and a is not 0</s> ${}\ \ ad-bc\ne0$.

Let $f(z) = \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$.  Functions of this kind are called "linear fractional transformations".  Then if $z$ moves around a circle in the complex plane, then $f(z)$ follows either a circle, although usually it's not the same circle, or a straight line.  It will be a straight line if and only if $z$ passes through some point that makes the denominator $0$.  Except when $c=0$, you'll find that it doesn't move at the same angular rate, i.e. when $z$ goes through a quarter of a circle, then $f(z)$ might go through a half circle.

In your example, $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=1$, and $d=2$.

Google the terms "linear fractional transformation" and "Riemann sphere".

**PS:** It is also the case that if $z$ moves along a straight line then $f(z)$ moves along either a straight line or a circle.

Comment: Do you want to let $z$ be complex as well? Or did you mean my $z$?

Comment: I changed it to say "If $z$ moves around a circle in the complex plane".  That would mean my "$z$" is your "$e^{it}$" and my "$f(z)$" is your "$z$".

Comment: @Michael thanks...

Comment: By hindsight I'm surprised that I said $a$ should not be $0$.  All of this works if $a=0$, unless $ad-bc=0$.